# How can I edit and run a python file .py with IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname

class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, first, last, staffnum):
        super().__init__(first, last)
        self.staffnumber = staffnum


x = Person("Marge", "Simpson")
y = Employee("Homer", "Simpson", "1007")

print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. You should revisit your question and edit it in order to amend more information. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I changed title to a comprehensible question.  If not right, explain better what you are asking.  It is not clear why you posted the particular code you did.

Comment: Yes you are right. i try running the codes on the IDLE but am having "invalid syntax" i was wondering if is happens to the type of version i have please i help me out i have a test study with this question on Andela institute.....

Comment: the question is an example i needed to practice but each time i run it in my python IDLE  it returns "invalid syntax"

Answer (score 1):

Answering what I think you mean.

Start IDLE either from icon or command line.  Detail depend on OS and a bit on Python version.

Load file into an IDLE editor window using File => Open menu option and the open-file dialog.  If a file had been edited recently, use File => Recent files.

Edit as you wish.  Run with Run => Run module or use F5 shortcut.

If you start IDLE from a command line, optionally add a file path, either relative or absolute, to open the file directly and skip the File menu.